# How to measure the height of the content and split into multiple parts and display on 2 pages in TCPDF by PHP?

Tags: php, split, height, tcpdf

[Issue on length of the string in TCPDF (Click to view image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4C0o.jpg)

UPDATED Image for explanation:

[I want to generate PDF as this format (Click to view image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3Sb.jpg)

[Not generate PDF like this (Click to view image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgl49.jpg)

I have the issue to split the body content (string) into multiple part and add the content into new page.

Following are the coding to measure height of the page to force generate content into new page, but I do not know how to generate content and display on page 1 and page 2 together with given height of footer. Currently only detect the height for footer and whole content generate into page 2.

```
$A4Y = 300;
$y = $pdf->GetY();
$x = $pdf->GetX();

while($products){
    $pdf->SetY($y);
    $pdf->SetX($x);
    $pdf->multicell($wc=65,5,html_entity_decode($product_desc),0,'L');       

    $offsety1=$pdf->GetY();

    if( ($A4Y-($offsety1+10)) < 48){
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $y = $pdf->GetY();
        $x = $pdf->GetX();
    }
}
```

As from above coding, after AddPage(), getting new coordinate -X and -Y, in new loop, write the $product_desc in new page, otherwise new loop write on same page as previous loop.

Comment: Have you tried if auto page break works? $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 0);

Comment: I do have auto page break, but I am formatting the border by using $pdf->Line(). The content causes my result of the calculation not apply on continuous page of content.